# Ensure PubSub batch requests are sent in Google Cloud Run Node App

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a NodeJS server running in a container in Google Cloud Run. It publishes messages to PubSub.

```
// during handling a request, 
const topic = pubsub.topic(topicName, {
    batching: {
        maxMessages: 1000,
        maxMilliseconds: 1000,
    },
});

// publish some messages
someArray.forEach((item) => {
    topic.publishJSON(item);
});
```

Let's assume someArray.length is less than maxMessages.
What happens if the Node sends a response before maxMilliseconds has elapsed? Are the messages sent? Does Google Cloud Run kill the container upon the http response, or does it somehow know that the PubSub library has set a timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Run doesn't kill the container immediately, but it [limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#avoiding_background_activities) its access to  CPU after processing the request. As the documentation suggests finish all the asynchronous tasks within request handling. Try async/await like in [the example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching).